# Wordpress Post Format update manually from Database Not Reflecting in Post Edit Page in Admin

Tags: php, wordpress, post-format

In Wordpress, I have updated post format through custom API. Following steps, I have done

1. Added the new post format id(term_taxonomy_id) in wp_term_relationships table and deleted the previous id.
2. Clear cache of wordpress by wp_cache_flush

But it still showing old post format in post edit page in admin.

Am I missing something?

I really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you updated the actual post and not a revision?

Comment: Yes it's a actual post because I have just update the term_taxonomy_id value in relationship table